# How proof functions prove?

Tags: coq

It'd help my understanding the 'programs/proofs' parallelism if somebody was kind enough to explain me how the proof function is used in the following simple case:

```
Theorem ex1: forall n:nat, 7*5 < n -> 6*6 <= n. 
Proof.
  intros.
  assumption.
Qed.
```

The proof function:

```
ex1 = fun (n : nat) (H : 7 * 5 < n) => H
     : forall n : nat, 7 * 5 < n -> 6 * 6 <= n
```

Is the proof function executed in the proof process? How its return value is used?
Is it correct to say that the return value of `ex1` is an instance of the type `forall n : nat, 7 * 5 < n -> 6 * 6 <= n` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it correct to say that the return value of `ex1` is an instance of the type `forall n : nat, 7 * 5 < n -> 6 * 6 <= n` ?

Not quite. It would be more correct to say that the return type of `ex1` is `6 * 6 <= n`, where `n` is the first argument passed to `ex1`, or that `ex1` has type `forall n, 7 * 5 < n -> 6 * 6 <= n`.

> Is the proof function executed in the proof process?

Not necessarily. Execution here means "simplification" or "normalization". The term built by the proof is usually not simplified.  For example:

```
Theorem foo : True.
Proof.
assert (H : True -> True).
{ intros H'. exact H'. }
apply H.
exact I. (* I is a proof of True *)
Qed.

Print foo.

(* foo = let H : True -> True := fun H' : True => H' in 
         H I *)
```

Simplifying this proof means replacing `H` by `fun H' : True => H'` and reducing the application, which yields `I`.  You can see this by asking Coq to compute this term:

```
Compute let H : True -> True := fun H' : True => H' in H I.
(* = I : True *)
```

*However*:

> How its return value is used?

Every proof that you enter in Coq goes a type-checking step to ensure it is correct.  One of the things the type checker does is to simplify terms when comparing their types.  In Coq, two terms that compute to the same normal form are considered equal.  The term given in the result, `H`, was given type `7 * 5 < n`.  But `a < b` is defined as `S a <= b`; thus we can also view `H` as having type `S (7 * 5) <= n`.  Coq now needs to ensure that `H` has type `6 * 6 <= n`, which it does, because the two lower bounds compute to 36.  Thus, there is computation happening when you enter a proof in Coq, but the computation is performed by the type-checker, not the proof term (even though the proof term does have computational behavior).